# yelp cannot find GNOME help files

Tags: gnome, helpfile, yelp

### tl;dr

The summary of all the following is roughly this:

- Remove or move the directory `/usr/share/help/C/gnome-help`.
- Run the command `sudo apt reinstall gnome-user-docs gnome-getting-started-docs ubuntu-docs`.
- The missing directory and its contents must come back.

This works OK in one of my 20.04 system, but not on another 20.04 system. Both systems are up-to-date.

I want to find out what makes this difference.

---

---

After upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04 the GNOME *Help* application (`yelp`) cannot find GNOME help files. For example, when I am in the GNOME *Files* application (`nautilus`) and press <kbd>F1</kbd> I get the following error message in the `yelp` window:

```
Document Not Found
The URI ‘help:gnome-help/files’ does not point to a valid page.
```

The same thing occurs in other GNOME applications, like `gedit`, `gnome-calculator` etc.

`yelp` can display the `man` pages OK. The problem is only with the "help" pages. Is there any package that needs to be installed?

I tried to install package `gnome-user-guide`, but it didn't help. Packages:

```
gnome-getting-started-docs
gnome-user-docs
ubuntu-docs
xorg-docs-core
```

are already installed and up-to-date.

---

It seems* that the files needed are the ones under `/usr/share/help/C/gnome-help/` and the package `gnome-user-docs` is the one that provides these (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/gnome-user-docs/filelist). However, even removing, purging and re-installing this package does not bring these files to my system.

*Note: `dpkg -S /usr/share/help/C/gnome-help/files.page` output is this:

```
gnome-user-docs: /usr/share/help/C/gnome-help/files.page
```

Also `ls -lisad /usr/share/help/ /usr/share/help/C` output is:

```
8651957 4 drwxr-xr-x 59 root root 4096 May 14 19:55 /usr/share/help/
8651631 4 drwxr-xr-x 31 root root 4096 May 17 17:39 /usr/share/help/C
```

and permissions and ownership of the files within these directories is `-rw-r--r--   root root`.

---

Similarly, other GNOME packages (for example, `gnome-calculator`) when (re)installed, they do **not** populate the relevant directory under `/usr/share/help/C/`.

I tested by copying `/usr/share/help/C/gnome-help/` directory and its contents from another system and then reinstalling the `gnome-user-docs` package. The re-installation deleted the necessary files which I just copied there! **Before doing the re-installation, but after copying these files manually, `yelp` was able to display its home screen and the relevant help screens OK.** After the re-installation, the above mentioned problem occurs.

---

I have tried with various locales with the installation of  `gnome-user-docs` package. Every time the same thing occurs. The files that I copied manually under `/usr/share/help/C/` are being deleted:

```
# LANG=en_US.UTF-8 apt --reinstall install gnome-user-docs
# LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 apt --reinstall install gnome-user-docs
# LANG=C.UTF-8     apt --reinstall install gnome-user-docs
```

My `locale` output is this:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

(Note that I tested with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` also; result was the same.)

The output of `check-language-support --show-installed` is:

```
firefox-locale-en gimp-help-en hunspell-en-au hunspell-en-ca hunspell-en-gb hunspell-en-us hunspell-en-za hyphen-en-ca hyphen-en-gb hyphen-en-us language-pack-en language-pack-gnome-en libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za mythes-en-au mythes-en-us poppler-data thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb thunderbird-locale-en-us wamerican wbritish
```

---

Currently installed packages:

```
# apt --installed list | grep -i "docs"

gnome-getting-started-docs/focal,focal,now 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
gnome-user-docs/focal,focal,now 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 all [installed]
ubuntu-docs/focal,focal,now 20.04.2 all [installed]
xorg-docs-core/focal,focal,now 1:1.7.1-1.1 all [installed,automatic]
```

---

## More Information

### (1)

The output of `sudo apt-cache depends yelp` is like this:

```
yelp
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
  Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
  Depends: libyelp0
 |Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend
  Depends: <gsettings-backend>
    dconf-gsettings-backend
  Depends: python3-distro
  Depends: yelp-xsl
  Depends: man-db
    man-db:i386
  Recommends: docbook-xml
```

Note: This is the *same* output as on another system *which does not have this problem*.

### (2)

The checksums for the `yelp` package are OK:

```
$ debsums yelp | wc -l
230
$ debsums yelp | grep 'OK$' | wc -l
230
$ debsums -a yelp | grep 'OK$' | wc -l
230
```

However, the checksums for the `gnome-user-docs` package show inconsistent results. On the system with this problem:

```
$ debsums gnome-user-docs | wc -l
4
$ debsums gnome-user-docs | grep 'OK$' | wc -l
4
$ debsums -a gnome-user-docs | grep 'OK$' | wc -l
4
$ debsums gnome-user-docs
/usr/share/doc/gnome-user-docs/NEWS.gz                                        OK
/usr/share/doc/gnome-user-docs/README                                         OK
/usr/share/doc/gnome-user-docs/changelog.Debian.gz                            OK
/usr/share/doc/gnome-user-docs/copyright                                      OK
```

Whereas on a system without this problem:

```
$ debsums gnome-user-docs | wc -l
465
```

and the difference is in the `/usr/share/help/C/gnome-help/` and `/usr/share/help/C/system-admin-guide/` files: The files I am talking about throughout this post.

Comment: Can you show the output of `sudo apt-cache depends yelp`, please?

Comment: Okay, then `sudo apt-cache depends yelp | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt-get --reinstall install` does not help getting it fixed on your system? Which would reinstall all dependencies of yelp...

Comment: FYI - the `apt-cache` do not need `sudo` to operate normally.

Comment: @N0rbert Okay, thank you.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli what is your current `locale`? And what is the output of `dpkg -S gnome-help/files.page`?

Comment: @starkus You command was this: `apt-get --reinstall install libc6 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libyelp0 dconf-gsettings-backend python3-distro yelp-xsl man-db`. After executing it, a reboot was requested due to `libc6`. After reboot a ran `apt --reinstall install gnome-user-docs` and the same thing happened! The necessary files for `yelp` where deleted.

Comment: Maybe something due to missing rights? What is the output of `ls -lisa /usr/share/help`?

Comment: Mine is empty too. I read that gnome-user-docs breaks gnome-user-guide. Do have this installed on your system?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli please show the output of `dpkg -S gnome-help/files.page`.

Comment: @starkus `gnome-user-guide` is not installed. I updated my OP.

Comment: The output of `check-language-support --show-installed` maybe useful too.

Comment: The checksums are valid? You could check them with `debsums gnome-user-docs` and `debsums yelp`

Comment: They are OK. However, please read Note #2 at the end of my OP: `gnome-user-docs` has the problem. I changed the software download server also and tested with other servers. Always the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The culprit is the `localepurge` package

After doing some further investigation, I found out that on my problematic system a package called `localepurge` was installed, while on the non-problematic system that package was not installed.

For more information you can look at  [the man page of localepurge](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/localepurge.8.html)

There was a file `/etc/locale.nopurge` that did not include the `C` locale, to exclude it from purging files created under it.

Anyway, I did not remember installing `localepurge` package, so I removed it. And then I re-ran:

```
# apt reinstall gnome-user-docs gnome-getting-started-docs ubuntu-docs xorg-docs-core
```

The missing files came back.

In the man page a script called `/usr/share/doc/localepurge/reinstall_debs.sh` is mentioned, which effectively is this:

```
apt-get -u --reinstall --fix-missing install $(dpkg -S LC_MESSAGES | cut -d: -f1 | tr ', ' '\n' | sort -u)
```

I ran that command also.

Comment: Interesting. Good to read you got it fixed.

Comment: You are not the first who encountered issues after having used `localepurge`. It's apparently a dangerous tool, and I wouldn't even think of using it. Anyway, good that you fixed it. And that you confirmed my preconceptions of `localepurge`. ;)